# selected class not working jquery function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

the function below show/hides divs into tabs so you can tab between the different divs. In addition it uses ben alman's bbq plugin http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/ which allows you to use the back button on your browser when tabbing between the divs.

everything works but i can't get the link of the clicked tab to show as 'selected'. when you click on a tab it should add a "selected" class to the a link so it shows as selected.

```
$(function () {
var tabContainers = $('div.tabs > div');
  tabContainers.hide().filter(':first').show();

  $(window).bind('hashchange', function () {
    var hash = window.location.hash || '#divContainer';

    tabContainers.hide();
    tabContainers.filter(hash).show();
    $('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
    $('a[hash=' + hash + ']').addClass('selected');
  });

  $(window).trigger( "hashchange" );
});
```

Comment: instead of `$('a[hash='` don't you mean `$('a[href='`?

Answer (score 1):

First save the anchor in a var at start of function
`var currenct_anchor = $(this);`

then

```
$('div.tabs ul.tabNavigation a').removeClass('selected');
currenct_anchor.addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you aren't using

tabContainers.filter(hash).addClass('selected');

It looks like you use that form several times for things like .show() -- do those commands work?

Ultimately it looks like your problem is that you aren't correctly selecting the element that you want to select.  I would suggest adding in some console.log(hash) to get a better sense of what the variables are storing.  Make sure you are accessing the objects that you want.